# Помогите грамотно составить SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В общем имеется одна таблица, которая собирает поисковые запросы на сайте.
В таблице есть поле самого запроса и ИД соеденения.
Суть в том, что когда пользователь кидает запрос, в базу фиксируется это значение. Пользователь получает список результатов, и возможно на нескольких страницах. Вот когда он выбирает следующию страницу, в базу пишиться снова этот же запрос. Это повторные записи нужны, для статистики. Но в данном случае, мне нужно получить рейтинг запросов, не учитывая вот эти постраничные записи.
Для этого и существует поле ID Connection.
Надо запустить запрос, чтоб получить два столба - слово и кол-во запросов.
И обязательно исключать повторения комбинаций query-id_connection, т.е. учитывать только один раз эту комбинацию.

Вот пример запроса и результата.

Имеем данные(поля: query - id_conn):

```
abc - 111
abc - 111
def - 111
def - 222
xyz - 333
```

В результате должно выдать:

```
abc - 1
def - 2
xyz - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select query, count(distinct connection) from smth group by query
```